# Azure cdn purge cli

Tags: azure, azure-cdn, purge

I do have some problem to understand how the azure cli can purge works and affect the cdn caching and engine rules.

In my resource group I have a CDN Endpoint, and this endpoint have some engine rules declared.

When I updated my storage account with new files, I am able to manually(through the portal) purge this contents and everything works just fine and my engine rules are preserved.On the other hand, if I want to automate this process with a azure DevOps pipeline, and run the command:

`az cdn endpoint purge  -g <my-resource-group> -n <cdn-name> --profile-name <cdn-profile-name> --content-paths "/*"`

What happens is that this command run successfully and it does purge the CDN cache and it also deletes all my engine rules, occurring in a downtime (as I need to create all the engine rule again).

And this is what is confusing me, why when I purge manually through the portal, the engine rules are preserved, and if I do the same with az cli, it kills all my engine rules.

Can please please, anyone help me to sort out this issue and be able to run a az cli command to simple purge the cache without killing my engine rules every time.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Do you use a SAS token when you access the content of your storage bob with Azure cdn? What's the engine rules that killed every time?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?